# Resolve batched query in single api call on apollo graphql server

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, batching

I am currently using batching of similar calls on apollo graphql client.
So it sends single call to `apollo-server` if same graphql query is fired but with different parameters.

But on graphql server side I want to optimize such that there also a single call goes to resolve all graphql queries at once.

Graphql server makes call to api server but for each single batched call, not to resolve all queries at once.

I have used `data-loader` to use batching but it sends single request only.

```
  genUserInfoDataLoader() {
    return new DataLoader(async (arr) => {
      logger.info(`---> UserInfoDataLoader Making calls for:${JSON.stringify(arr)}`);
      const leagueId = arr[0].split(':')[1];
      const UserIds = arr.map(a => a.split(':')[0]);
      const userInfoMap = await this.post('endpoint/user-info ', {
        userIds: UserIds.join(','),
        tourId,
      });

      return UserIds
        .map(
         userId => (userInfoMap[userId] ? userInfoMap[userId] : [])
        );
    });
  }
```